# AOT build error with BrowserAnimationsModule in platform-browser

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot

I'm currently working with Angular 4 and also apply Ahead-of-time compilation to reduce the amount of the boostrap time to my application. Everything is working fine but there is only one trouble when I try to apply some transition animation between states to the application.

I follow this [solution](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example.).

When I try to build AOT by the command:

```
"ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js"
```

It always ends up with this error :

> "Unexpected value 'BrowserAnimationsModule in
>   /home/alex/Documents/htdocs/music_performance/assets/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/index.d.ts'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule in
>   /home/alex/Documents/htdocs/music_performance/assets/app/app.module.ts'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation."

Here is my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

//SOME_COMPONENTS_IMPORT

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [Globals],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Other configurations for AOT and roll-up, I do exactly same as this documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html
Thank for your help.

Comment: What versions are you using? BrowserAnimationsModule got moved in 4.0.0 RC1 I think.

Comment: All @angular components are currently run at v4.1.3. I also got the demo of animations from angular.io that runs at v4.0.0. However, when I build on the terminal, it still appears the same errors. I don't know why. Is there any suggestion? Thanks